# Mock an abstract base class using EasyMock

Tags: java, unit-testing, junit, mocking, easymock

I have an abstract base class (parent) and a derived class (child)

```
public class child extend parent{
    public void child(...) {
        super(..)
    }
}

public abstract class parent{
   .
   .
   .
}
```

Here I want to test a public method in child class. And I don't have any dependency in parent class. so I want to mock my abstract parent class. Couldn't find any solid example of doing it. Please share your suggestion.

Answer (score 2):

You cannot do this. `child` is a subclass of `parent`. You cannot change this. The best you can do is mock all dependancies in `parent`.